# Running gedit in background

Tags: 12.04, bash, gedit, bashrc

So I've got this working in a 10.04 ubuntu OS in bash where I can run:

```
$ gedit app/file.rb
```

bash opens that file with gedit but it is tied up.

How can I make my earlier command equivalent to `$ gedit app/file.rb  &` by default.

If it helps here is a copy of my .bashrc file from the 10.04 OS : http://pastie.org/4687219

Comment: is this even a question?

Answer (score 4):

ignite is right. but still, I would create this function:

```
function gedit(){ command gedit "$@" &>/dev/null & }
```

throwing the output to /dev/null keeps your terminal clean and allows you to continue your work.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your .bashrc file:

```
function gedit(){ command gedit "$@" & }
```

Now restart your terminal. `gedit app/file.rb` should now run in background.

[Source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html)